# how to make sure to close the right Chromium window from linux commandline?

Tags: linux, command-line, google-chrome, bash

I'm writing a little bash script that opens a couple of applications (several chrome windows among others), waits for input, and with the correct input closes all the opened applications again.

For terminating the applications I found out two different ways:
either with `kill $PID`
or with `wmctrl -c <WIN>`

In my case there are several chromium windows open (not only the ones launched by the script).
The window title of chrome changes with the URL that is visited, so in my eyes using `wmctrl -c` is not very helpful. Additionaly, if another window (e.g. an instance of Firefox) has a similar window tiltle, it will get closed as well.

That leads me to the `kill` command. But I couldn't figure out how to identify the PID of the Chrome Window that I want to terminate.

I tried this:

```
pid=$(ps | grep chromium | cut -d " " -f1 | head -n1)
if [ -n "$pid" ]
    then
        echo "...Closing Chromium"
        kill -15 $pid
    else
        echo "...Chromium not found"
fi
```

but it closes all Chromium windows.

Any idea how to identify the chrome window that I want to kill?

Comment: Consider using `pgrep -f` which you can use to identify the right process/window.

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models ,**You can't close a tab by killing the process. The process represents a renderer that the main browser uses the execute and draw a page, which it then copies to the screen**

Answer (score 1):

Try this project: http://chromix.smblott.org/

you should be able to run something like this then:

```
chromix with https://www.facebook.com/ close
```

Comment: Hmm...this seems pretty clever. You should describe the software you're recommending, though; link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or goes offline.

Comment: For anyone noticing that the link in the answer is, indeed, broken here's the GitHub page for chromix, though I don't know if it's still usable (last commit was a few years ago): https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix

Answer (score 0):

the bash manual says:

```
       $!      Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command.
```

so store all your desired PIDs directly after starting the chromium process. Perhaps like this:

```
chromium & job1=$!
echo job1=$job1
#...
kill $job1
```

there are arrays in bash also for lists of PIDs...

Comment: This is what I tried, but unfortunately didn't work. I think the reason for this is what BlueBerry already mentioned. You can't close a tab by killing the process.
Until now, I only succeeded in killing all Chrome windows ever created or non at all. I think I'll try to rename the window with `wmctrl -T` and see whether I am able to close single windows with `wmctrl -c`